# image overlay another image

Tags: html, css, image

On [MY WEBSITE](http://www.khwebdesign.co.uk/portfolio.php)
I have this code:

```
<div>
    <center><a href="foo.html"><img src="images/ipadframe.png" width="200" height="300"></a></center>
  </div>  
<div style="position:absolute; left:233; top:35;">
    <img src="images/xclomobi.jpg" width="152" height="233">
</div>
            <div class="section_w280 fl">
                <ul class="future_project"><br><br>
                    <li>Website: <a href="#" target="new">#</a></li>
                    <li>Role:<font size="2"> CSS / PHP / MYSQL</font></li>
                    <li>#li>
                </ul>
                <div class="cleaner"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="section_w140 fr"><br><br>
                <div class="rc_btn_02"><a href="#">Visit</a></div>
                <div class="cleaner"></div>  
                </div>      

            <div class="margin_bottom_20 border_bottom"></div>         
</div>
```

which displays perfectly on my desktop but not on my ipad or smaller screens.

**how do I edit the div style above so that it loads reads an alternative code when viewing this on a device listed above?**

Is there a way to get it to display correctly no matter what device they are viewing it on?

Comment: For your site to be displayed correct on the mobile or smaller screen you sould use `responsive design`. For more information look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design.

Comment: You should also be aware that the `center>` element has been deprecated.

Comment: what should happen on smaller screens, where you can't fit in both divs side by side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is implement **Responsive design** by using `@media`querys...

**iPAD Portrait and Landscape**

`@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}`

**iPAD LANDSCAPE**

`@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}`

**iPAD PORTRAIT**

`@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }`

By using this, you can set the CSS styles only for that device...
Also need to read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)...

Comment: For iphone you need to implement the **resolutuion of device**... Of course you don't need to implement ALL `@media`query for ALL devices, you need to figure a way to implement your _HTML_ and _CSS_ general as possible, avoiding `px`and set sizes with `&`... You got a lot of concept to study, dude :)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative I find myself jumping into are responsive frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) or [Foundation by ZURB](http://foundation.zurb.com/).  They provide a stunning amount of components to get you on your responsive way in record time.  Both have their pros and cons, you should eval which one suits your needs.